# Random Forest Distance for Python fails to build (g++)

Tags: python, c++, g++, swig

this implementation of RFD http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jcorso/r/snippets.metric_learning.html
fails to build for me. Running the setup.py within the python package, when the following appears:

```
Building Swig Modules:
building librf...
/tmp/cctKDjwA.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cctKDjwA.s:12665: Error: no such instruction: `vfnmadd312ss 52(%r14),%xmm5,%xmm2'
/tmp/cctKDjwA.s:14338: Error: no such instruction: `vfnmadd312ss 84(%rdx),%xmm5,%xmm2'
/tmp/cctKDjwA.s:18244: Error: no such instruction: `vfnmadd312ss 228(%rsp),%xmm1,%xmm3'
/tmp/cctKDjwA.s:18389: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 272(%rsp),%xmm1,%xmm0'
```

The line where it fails (checked separately):

```
os.system("g++ -march=native -fPIC -O3 -std=c++0x -c src/librf_wrap.cxx src/librf/*.cc src/librf/semaphores/*.cpp -I/usr/include/" + pyver)
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with i5-4430. Apologies, but I'm unsure what additional info I should add, please suggest.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that '-march=native' is incorrectly determining your CPU and generating instructions that are illegal for it.
Could you try without '-march=native' to see if that is the case?

Note that it's possible to see what '-march=native' is choosing exactly, see [this website](http://en.chys.info/2010/04/what-exactly-marchnative-means/).